# Prove $(\vec a \times \vec b)\times(\vec c \times \vec d)=[\vec a,\vec b, \vec d]\vec c - [\vec a, \vec b, \vec c]\vec d$

Tags: proof-verification, vectors

> Let $\mathbf{a,b,c,d} \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Prove that
>   $$
> \newcommand{\bvec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
> (\bvec a \times \bvec b)\times(\bvec c \times \bvec d) = 
>     \begin{vmatrix}
>         \vert & \vert & \vert \\
>         \bvec{a} & \bvec b & \bvec d \\
>         \vert & \vert& \vert
>     \end{vmatrix} \bvec c
>     - \begin{vmatrix}
>         \vert & \vert & \vert \\
>         \bvec{a} & \bvec b & \bvec c \\
>         \vert & \vert& \vert
>     \end{vmatrix}\bvec d
> $$

This is the progress I've made so far. I don't know what to do and it seems like a dead end, can someone please help me?

[image: part 1]
[image: part 2]

[My friend also tried solving this, and this is her example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfxBb.jpg)

Comment: By the way, do you know [Levi-Civita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) notation and the [summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)? These are often useful for proving these sorts of identities. This page has some discussion on proving the identity: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/prove-vector-quadruple-product-with-levi-civita-index-notation.769416/.

Comment: I'm still a total newbie in linear algebra, had about 10 classes so far. I spent about an hour trying to solve this with the knowledge I have, what I'm trying to say is I'm limited when it comes to this stuff, sorry

Comment: Thanks for the article, I'll trying seeing what's going on there ":)

Comment: In linear algebra (as in math generally) one needs *definitions* to prove things.  Its going to be guesswork for Readers whether your difficulty is with a lack of definitions for the notation involved, or with details of calculations once those definitions are given.  The linked images can be (with difficulty) converted to mathematical expressions [usable in your post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), but even these do not precisely explain where you are having difficulty.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [$\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) (pending peer review).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll use that next time, I searched how to write vectors properly, so this will be a nice help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the identity
$$
\mathbf{a}\times (\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{c}) = (\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c})\mathbf{b} -(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}) \mathbf{c}?
$$
A brief proof of this identity is given on the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product) for the triple product.

With this result, your proof becomes straightforward: 
\begin{align}
(\mathbf a \times \mathbf b)\times(\mathbf c \times \mathbf d) &= \left( (\mathbf a \times \mathbf b) \cdot \mathbf{d} \right) \mathbf{c} - \left( (\mathbf a \times \mathbf b) \cdot \mathbf{c} \right) \mathbf{d}\\
&= \det\begin{bmatrix}
        \vert & \vert & \vert \\
        \mathbf{a} & \mathbf b & \mathbf d \\
        \vert & \vert& \vert
    \end{bmatrix} \mathbf c
    - \det\begin{bmatrix}
        \vert & \vert & \vert \\
        \mathbf{a} & \mathbf b & \mathbf c \\
        \vert & \vert& \vert
    \end{bmatrix}\mathbf d
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Use the triple product identities
$$({\bf x} \times {\bf y}) \times {\bf z} = -({\bf y} \cdot {\bf z}) {\bf x} + ({\bf x} \cdot {\bf z}) {\bf y},$$
and $$\pmatrix{{\bf x}&{\bf y}&{\bf z}} = ({\bf x} \times {\bf y}) \cdot {\bf z}.$$